# Core Data: retrieve all item entities grouped by date?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data entity called Item that has a date field. I'd like to retrieve all Items in my database grouped by date, e.g.:

```
Item one, date: 1/1/11
Item two, date: 1/1/11
Item three, date: 1/2/11
```

should return:

```
(Item one, Item two), (Item three)
```

Can someone tell me whats the best way to do this? thanks!

Comment: BTW, it's considered a good idea to mark an answer as correct if it helps with your problems.  If my answer wasn't good enough, let me know and I can update it.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do is to order them, and then create groupings based on identical dates.  (NOte:  while I am using real function names as appropriate, this is only psuedocode.  Fill in the gaps yourself, or if you need more help ask)

```
NSFetchRequest *request=[NSFetchRequest alloc init];
NSSortDescriptor *sort=[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"foo" ascending:YES];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
//Fetch

NSMutableArray* master=[NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* current=[NSMutableArray array];
NSDate *lastDate=[fetchedObjectsArray objectAtIndex:0].date;
forin(ManagedObjectSubclass *foo in fetchedObjectsArray)
{
//You'll need to figure out an algorithm to determine if two dates are the same.
//This code WILL NOT work as written.
    if(foo.date == lastDate)
    {
        [current addObject:foo];
    }
    else
    {
        [master addObject:current];
        current=[NSMutableArrayArrwayWithObject foo];
    }
}
[master addObject:current];
```

That should be more than enough to get you started.